# Project example/template for a simple LIFT + Mongo REST web service

Tags: scala, lift

I'm trying to build a web App using Lift to simply get the fields required from a Json POST and return an appropirate Json response.

I'm new to lift and am having trouble with identifying what to modify, where to put my logic... etc

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Building a RESTful backend with Lift is pretty straightforward. Have a look at the chapter "[HTTP and REST](http://stable.simply.liftweb.net/#toc-Chapter-5)" of Simply Lift.
If you experience troubles understanding the partial function stuff in Lift's RestHelper read the thread "[Help understanding RestHelper serve params](http://groups.google.com/group/liftweb/browse_thread/thread/a2834718fddc1f45)" in Lift's mailing list.

Answer (score 1):

Note: I am currently only allowed two URLs per answer and therefore have to split my answer in two parts.

To get started with Lift and MongoDB you could clone the project [lift-mongo-protouser](https://github.com/eltimn/lift-mongo-protouser) at github.
For more information about Lift and MongoDB read the [MongoDB releated articles](http://www.assembla.com/spaces/liftweb/wiki/MongoDB) in Lift's wiki.
If then you still have questions ask them at the Lift mailing list. People are really helpful over there.